# Community bumping questions

Tags: discussion

"Community" regularly bumps older questions which have answers with very few of zero upvotes. [This one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25679/using-arduino-flora-as-a-general-purpose-id-badge) a couple of minutes ago. But OP asked the question on the 26th of January, and hasn't been here since 31st of January. He hasn't even seen the single answer, that came later. Is it useful to bump those questions. *I* am not very motivated to answer it.

Shouldn't the system take the OP's activity into account?

Comment: As a note, I am tempted to close said question. The user is kind of doing off the wall style brainstorming. This type of question is not really interesting because there is no right answer and it is more of a discussion. This falls under a should be closed but no one else has shown interest so i am leaving it be as it is a boundary one.

Answer (score 3):

Community bumps any questions which are unanswered, where 'unanswered' means that they have zero upvoted or accepted answers.  It pulls randomly from [the 'unanswered' tab](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered).  You'll note that there are quite a few questions with multiple zero-voted answers on the later pages in that list.

Additional justification is given on the network-wide meta [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41877) and on the blog [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/).  In that blog post, while considering the difference between 'the OP has selected an accepted answer' and 'the community has selected an answer through voting', Jeff noted:

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. Heck, we don’t even expect people asking questions to come back and accept an answer most of the time.

The bar for asking a question is quite low.  This is intentional, the OP is just one person who might have that problem.  You don't even have to register an account to ask a question. If the question is good enough to stay open it deserves an answer regardless of the activity of the author.

So, if you want to prevent a question from being bumped, (1) create a good answer that will get upvoted or (2) upvote an existing answer (if it deserves the upvote-otherwise see (1)).

Comment: But, like I also commented to Nick's answer, if nobody seems to be interested in the given answers, not even OP, then what's the use if *I* write another answer nobody cares about. Some questions just are not interesting.

Comment: @stevenvh, edit it! if it is on topic and well written it should be of some interest to someone.

Comment: @stevenvh - Apparently, it has 174 views so it must be useful to someone.  Future utility is difficult to predict, so we simply assume that the question is valuable if it isn't downvoted or closed.

Comment: @Kevin: Views and usefulness are very different things.  I often view a question and then get out of there after realizing it is pointless, silly, unintersting, not in my area, or it would take too much just to explain why the question makes no sense.  Most likely one of those 174 views is me thinking "screw this".

Comment: @Kevin - again agree with Olin. It's not 174 views that make a question interesting, it's the number of reaction, comments, upvotes and answers. A title doesn't always say it all, so you click a question (+1 view!) to find that it's not what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Questions and answers are independent of who posted them (they are community property).  If they're unanswerable, they should be closed (then Community ♦ won't bump them), if it's a bad question, downvote (also think Community ♦ will refrain from bumping).  If they are answerable, then they should be, and once a good (upvoted) answer is posted, then problem solved (both).

For more, see [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99672/community-should-discriminate-more-when-bumping-unanswered-questions) on MSO.

Comment: This question had one answer with zero upvotes. So it looks like nobody is really interested in the question and its solutions. Why should I work to produce a good/better answer?